# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call - Early EOF

Tags: java, gwt, jetty, jetty-9

I am getting an Early EOF exception when i'm closing my webapplication. But i am only getting this exception when i close it in Edge. In chrome, safari and IE nothing is shown.

I am using GWT 2.8.1 and Jetty 9.4.2.v20170220 and this is the stacktrace i am getting:

```
[9635fa] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.getError(HttpInput.java:1111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.noContent(HttpInput.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:307)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContent(RPCServletUtils.java:224)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPCServletUtils.readContentAsGwtRpc(RPCServletUtils.java:252)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.readContent(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:182)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:364)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at com.bla.bla.bla.modules.systemconfig.GWTCacheControlFilter.doFilter(GWTCacheControlFilter.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at com.bla.bla.bla.core.webserver.WebServerManager$WebServerHandler.handle(WebServerManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.earlyEOF(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.parseRequestBuffer(HttpConnection.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I already red of posts on stackoverflow but nothing seems to awnser my question.

So if anyone knows what might cause this exception, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.